# Show that $f=0$ almost everywhere on E

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a non-negative bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure $E$. Assume that $\int f=0$ over $E$. Show that $f=0$ a.e. on E.

I want to prove this without using Chebychev's inequality proof. any idea
by the way i already solve it, it is just that i am curious if anyone know a different proofs

Comment: Consider the subset $E_\varepsilon \subseteq E$ where $f(x) \ge \varepsilon \gt 0$.  What can you say about the measure of $E_\varepsilon$?

Comment: can i say that $E_k$ is measurable

Comment: Yes, since $f$ is a measurable function.

Comment: Any reason you want to avoid using chevyshev/markov?

Comment: no particular reason, i was talking to my classmate about this problem automatically he said chevyshev and that is how i was able to solve it. then afterwards i got curious if there is another way i could prove it without using chevyshev

Comment: @user146269, those curiosities are good, I have always believed proofs from first principals can be quite enlightening for a subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon>0$, set $E_\epsilon=\{x\in E \colon f(x)\geq\epsilon\}$. Then $E_\epsilon$ is measurable since $f$ is, and $\mu(E_\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$ since otherwise (if,say, $\mu(E_\epsilon)=\delta>0$) we would have $\int_Efd\mu\geq\int_{E_\epsilon}fd\mu\geq\delta\epsilon$.